# Generating Multivariate Outliers in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution, dataset, outliers

I have generated a data-set following the Gaussian distribution with 5 dimensions. The data-set is 1Million record and I am seeking planting 20% outliers, is there a more neat way in R to generate such outliers other than generating them by changing the parameters of the Gaussian distribution function?

Comment: R implementation questions are off-topic here, but you seem to have a statistics question, too. What, though, makes you think that changing the parameters of the Gaussian distribution will create more outliers?

Comment: See [posts with "rmix" in them](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=rmix*+score%3A1) for various univariate examples.  They are readily generalized to multivariate distributions (use `MASS::mvrnorm`).

Comment: @Dave, thank you for making this clear. I thought that if I generated already 80% of the data to be correlated with specific mean and variance then a 20% of uncorrelated data with different mean and variance would be considered as outliers. That what I thought of. Do you think this claim won't work for statistical reasons?

Comment: @whuber, Thak you for the reply. I already used the mvrnorm to generate the data, I was specifically asking about a way to contaminate this data with 20% of outliers.

Comment: If you generate 800 points from some distribution, say `mvrnorm(800, mu, S)`, as the points from your population of interest, and then generated 200 more points from some other distribution, say `mvrnorm(200, mu1, S1)`, then those other points are outliers, since they do not come from the same population. I do not, however, think that this is going to generate a data set that looks like you want it to look.(But `mvrnorm` is an R function that might interest you, as it samples from multivariate normal distributions.)

Comment: @Dave, yes that is exactly what I have done (using mvrnorm).  I was just afraid that for any statistical reasons those points may not be considered as outliers but your answer made me relived as it goes with how I thought of it. 
Thank you.

Comment: There aren't any statistical reasons I can conceive of to think of 20% of a large dataset as "outlying:" that's just too many.  I think we have to understand your question as asking how to generate a *multimodal* dataset or one that is *clustered.*  I think you didn't get the point of my first comment: those threads answer your question for the univariate case. Adapt them to this multivariate case.

Comment: @whuber I guess I am a bit confused now, Will go through the threads one more time. But I do understand that the outliers ratio is 'too many' as you pointed out and it drastically deviates from the real world case yet I am trying to establish a scalability test  for BACON algorithm for outlier detection and I relied on this source for the ratio of outliers.: 
https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-ssnotes/top/detecting-outliers-in-datasets/using-the-bacon-algorithm-for-outlier-detection.html